# Exporting Google action to Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have a google action which I am trying to export as an Alexa skill using these instructions. https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/alexa-exporter

The Alexa Skills Kit console asks for an HTTPS service endpoint, but I don't know what to set here
[image: Alexa skill kits endpoint]

Is it the same as the Webhook fulfillment URL in dialogflow ? [image: DialogFlow webhook URL]

Also when I try opening the https webhook url in the browser I get this error - 
Action Error: no matching intent handler for: null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not "export a Google Action" for use as a Skill.

What it does is let you use Dialogflow to help define the user Intents, phrases, and Slot Entities that the legacy Skill Console expected. In particular it does **not** send your Alexa voice commands to Dialogflow for processing. The "fulfillment" section for Dialogflow is not used for Alexa handling.

Alexa still expects either an AWS Lambda or an HTTPS webhook to be specified where you will do the processing using its JSON format.

Comment: thanks, so it is not that seamless then :) to export it to an alexa skill. Any idea about this error ? 
Action Error: no matching intent handler for: null

Comment: It sounds unrelated - I'd suggest asking that as a separate StackOverflow question and provide as much info as you can (how are you calling the Intent Handler... code if you can... etc)